# Python np.array example

Tags: python, neural-network

I am new to Python.

I am confused as to what is happening with the following:

`B = np.array([A[..., n:n+5] for n in (5*4, 5*5)])`

Where `A.shape = (60L, 128L, 128L)`

and `B.shape = (2L, 60L, 128L, 5L)`

I believe it is supposed to make some sort of image patch. Can someone explain to me what this does? This example is in the context of applying neural networks to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of A tells me that A is most likely an array of 60 grayscale images (batch size 60), with each image having a size of 128x128 pixels.

We have: `B = np.array([A[..., n:n+5] for n in (5*4, 5*5)])`. To better understand what's happening here, let's unpack this line in reverse:

`for n in (5*4, 5*5)`: This is the same as `for n in (20, 25)`. The author probably chose to write it in this way for some intuitive reason related to the data or the rest of the code. This gives us `n=20` and `n=25`.

`A[..., n:n+5]`: This is the same as `A[:, :, n:n+5]`. This gives us all the rows from all the images of in `A`, but only the 5 columns at `n:n+5`. The shape of the resulting array is then `(60, 128, 5)`.

`n=20` gives us `A[:, :, 20:25]` and `n=25` gives us `A[:, :, 25:30]`. Each of these arrays is therefore of size `(60, 128, 5)`.

Together, `[A[..., n:n+5] for n in (5*4, 5*5)]` gives us a list (thanks list comprehension!) with two elements, each a numpy array of size `(60, 128, 5)`. `np.array()` converts this list into a numpy array of shape `(2, 60, 128, 5)`.

The result is that `B` contains 2 patches of each image, each a 5 pixel column wide subset of the original image- one starting at column 20 and the second one starting at column 25.

I can't speculate to the reason for this crop without further information about the network and its purpose.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very nice answer. I appreciate the detail. This makes perfect sense now.